# OpenGL vertex at NDC (-1.0, -1.0) is at what sub-pixel position?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl

If in a shader I create a 2D vertex at position (x: -1.0 y: -1.0) directly in NDC, does that create the vertex at the center of the bottom-left pixel on screen, or at the bottom-left corner of that pixel?

I'm trying to align a quad to be drawn with perfect pixel position and size and can't figure out where the vertex is placed in the sub-pixel, the center or the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(-1,-1)` is at the bottom-left corner of the bottom-left pixel.

`(+1,+1)` is at the top-right corner of the top-right pixel.

Comment: Would that makes the NDC (1.0, 1.0) be the bottom-left corner of the top-right pixel? Or the top-right corner of the top-right pixel?

Comment: @user1043761 Top-right corner of the top-right pixel.